# My python script, which recursively renames files, fails

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, subprocess, substring

I'm trying to recursively rename the files in a directory, so I wrote a python script to handle the renaming. So ideally, the script should be able to turn this

```
Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:RenameXtalTest nick$ ls
RM01_03_000_0213_Proj1_Clon1_RC_0000RC000870_010_171222_01_03_02_E0_00_031_001_RAI.jpg
RM01_03_000_0213_Proj1_Clon1_RC_0000RC000870_010_171222_07_07_01_E0_99_031_001_RAI.jpg
rename.py
```

into

```
Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:RenameXtalTest nick$ ls
RC000870-C1_02-E0_00.jpg
RC000870-G7_01-E0_99.jpg
rename.py
```

I can get rename.py to work on a ***single name in Python*** if it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
oldname = 'RM01_03_000_0213_Proj1_Clon1_RC_0000RC000870_010_171222_01_03_02_E0_00_031_001_RAI.jpg'  #manually set an old name
rowdic = {"01" : "A", "02" : "B", "03" : "C", "04" : "D", "05" : "E", "06" : "F", "07" : "G", "08" : "H"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 59 to 61
coldic = {"01" : "1", "02" : "2", "03" : "3", "04" : "4", "05" : "5", "06" : "6", "07" : "7", "08" : "8", "09" : "9", "10" : "10", "11" : "11", "12" : "12"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 56 to 58
subwdic = {"01" : "1", "02" : "2", "03" : "3"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 62 to 64

newname = oldname[36:44]+"-"+rowdic[oldname[59:61]]+coldic[oldname[56:58]]+"_"+subwdic[oldname[62:64]]+"-"+oldname[65:70]+".jpg" #definition for how to shorten, rearrange, and swap out some parts of oldname

print newname
```

But as soon as I try to get the script to work on ***multiple files in Unix*** - it fails.  Here's my script attempt at the aforementioned:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
rowdic = {"01" : "A", "02" : "B", "03" : "C", "04" : "D", "05" : "E", "06" : "F", "07" : "G", "08" : "H"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 59 to 61
coldic = {"01" : "1", "02" : "2", "03" : "3", "04" : "4", "05" : "5", "06" : "6", "07" : "7", "08" : "8", "09" : "9", "10" : "10", "11" : "11", "12" : "12"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 56 to 58
subwdic = {"01" : "1", "02" : "2", "03" : "3"} #dictionary to translate oldname char 62 to 64
for oldname in os.listdir("."): #get list of all oldnames in current directory
    newname = oldname[36:44]+"-"+rowdic[oldname[59:61]]+coldic[oldname[56:58]]+"_"+subwdic[oldname[62:64]]+"-"+oldname[65:70]+".jpg" #definition for how to shorten, rearrange, and swap out some parts of oldname
    os.rename(oldname, newname) #command to change all old names to new names
```

and here's the error that I get when I try to run it:

```
Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:RenameXtalTest nick$ ./rename.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rename.py", line 7, in <module>
    newname = oldname[36:44]+"-"+rowdic[oldname[59:61]]+coldic[oldname[56:58]]+"_"+subwdic[oldname[62:64]]+"-"+oldname[65:70]+".jpg"
KeyError: ''
```

Can someone help me understand what the error means, and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you don't handle file names that aren't in that specific format. Try printing the value of `oldname`. It's probably giving you `.`, `..`, and `rename.py` in addition to the other files.

Comment: Yes, exactly what @mooiamaduck says. While it's not the best solution, you can simply include an if statement like `if len(oldname) > 70:` in your loop body to only perform the processing on file names that have more than 70 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the comments of @mooiamaduck and me gives this code:

```
for oldname in os.listdir("."):
    if len(oldname) < 70:
        continue 
    newname = oldname[36:44]+"-"+rowdic[oldname[59:61]]+coldic[oldname[56:58]]+"_"+subwdic[oldname[62:64]]+"-"+oldname[65:70]+".jpg"
    os.rename(oldname, newname) #command to change all old names to new names
```

The issue is basically that you are also processing files that don't have the specific filename format that you wish to rename. (For instance your `.`, `..` and `rename.py`.) `oldname[62:64]` for instance then translates to an empty string, which you will then use as key for your `subwdic` resulting in the empty string `KeyError`.

The simple fix proposed here is to only consider filenames that have at least 70 characters. A better solution of course would be to do a proper check on the filename to see if it matches your pattern but this will do just fine for your specific usecase.

Comment: YES IT WORKED. THANK YOU

Comment: Glenn Codes, what would be a good statement to only process the file name if it has ".jpg" in it?

Comment: Also, your final bit of code states "if len(oldname) < 70" which works.  This is not intuitive, as it says that it will only process names with less than 70 characters, which includes problematic names like rename.py and "."  If I switch it to "> 70", the script fails again.  Why?

Comment: If this `if` statement evaluates to `True` it will `continue`, meaning that it will skip the rest of the loop body and continue to the next file.

Comment: For checking if the filename ends with `.jpg` you can do `oldname.endswith(".jpg")`.